# Powershell - free disk space - bgcolor result how change

Tags: html, powershell

I have this script:

```
Function Get-ComInfo {   
param(

Computers
$computers

)
$FreespaceWarning = 30; $orangeColor = "#FBB917"

#Here LOW Space thresold is lessthan 10% of the total size of the Volume
$PercentFree = @{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.freespace /1GB)}} Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter "DriveType=3" -computer $computers |
Select SystemName,DeviceID,VolumeName,$PercentFree,@{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($.size/1gb)}},@{name="PercentFree(%)";Expression={int}}, @{Name="LOW SPACE";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($.freespace / $_.size -lt .1)}}

}

Get-Content U:\Users\test\Desktop\servers.txt | ForEach-Object { Get-ComInfo -computers $_} | ConvertTo-HTML | Out-File U:\Users\test\Desktop\Drives.htm
```

I want a computer that has less than 5GB of free space too appear in red color in the HTML. Who can help me? Because, I dont have ideas.

Comment: I dont know how use it.

Comment: Is it not for consol results? Because for hmtl result not work.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, then. I missed the part that you need it for HTML. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. Maybe help with html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

1. Write your HTML using the [ConvertTo-HTML cmdlet](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113290) and manipulate (add
   css) the html after.
2. Build your own HTML.

I would recommend you the second approach. Start with a template for your html and for your two for your entries (one "normal" and one for the entries with low disc space). Now you can build your html using string format and write it to disc using the [Out-File cmdlet](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113363).

Example:

```
$html=
@'
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  .alert {{
    background-color: #FBB917 }}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>SystemName</th><th>DeviceID</th><th>VolumeName</th><th>FreeSpace(GB)</th><th>Size(GB)</th><th>PercentFree(%)</th><th>LOW SPACE</th></tr>
{0}
</table>
</body></html>
'@

$entryTemplate = '<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td><td>{4}</td><td>{5}</td><td>{6}</td></tr>'
$alertEntryTemplate = '<tr class="alert"><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td><td>{4}</td><td>{5}</td><td>{6}</td></tr>'


Function Get-ComInfo {   
param(
$computers

)
$FreespaceWarning = 30; $orangeColor = "#FBB917"

#Here LOW Space thresold is lessthan 10% of the total size of the Volume
$PercentFree = @{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.freespace /1GB)}} 
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter "DriveType=3" -computer $computers |
Select SystemName,DeviceID,VolumeName,$PercentFree,@{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.size/1gb)}},@{name="PercentFree(%)";Expression={int}}, @{Name="LOW SPACE";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.freespace / $_.size -lt .1)}}

}

$entries = Get-Content U:\Users\test\Desktop\servers.txt | % { Get-ComInfo -computers $_ } | % {
    if ([float]::Parse($_.'FreeSpace(GB)') -le 5) {
        $alertEntryTemplate -f $_.SystemName, $_.DeviceID, $_.VolumeName, $_.'FreeSpace(GB)', $_.'Size(GB)', $_.'PercentFree(%)', $_.'LOW SPACE'
    }
    else {
        $entryTemplate -f $_.SystemName, $_.DeviceID, $_.VolumeName, $_.'FreeSpace(GB)', $_.'Size(GB)', $_.'PercentFree(%)', $_.'LOW SPACE'
    }
}

$html -f ($entries -join ' ') | out-file U:\Users\test\Desktop\Drives.htm
```

Comment: whats your error message? This works for me (except im not using a server list)

Comment: There are no errors . Just do not display results Size(GB) PercentFree and Low Space

Comment: Well, it doesn't show Size(GB) PercentFree and LowSpace because your script contains some bugs (`$.freespace` instead of `$_.freespace`). I fixed that even its not part of the question.

Comment: Ok, it is, but not colored results.

Comment: please post the complete html output (edit your question).

Comment: But i have not change nothing at your code. I can not HTML, and i dont know how write it.

Comment: You don't have to write html, you should just post the html generated by the script. Are there computer with freesize less than 5 Gb?

Comment: No, but i changed on if ($_.'FreeSpace(GB)' -le 100) and no red results.

Comment: Im beginners and I dont understand your solutions. I thought it was ready code. And what changed was less than 100GB, to see if the code works, because I have a computer that has less than 100GB.

Comment: so post us the content from your html file (U:\Users\test\Desktop\Drives.htm)

Comment: SystemName DeviceID VolumeName FreeSpace(GB) Size(GB) PercentFree(%) LOW SPACE
K005 C:  76,5 111,0  False
K005 U: Nowy 87,5 465,8

Comment: this is not the content from the html file. You have to open the file with an editor....

Comment: Content is in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  .alert {
    background-color: #FBB917 }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>SystemName</th><th>DeviceID</th><th>VolumeName</th><th>FreeSpace(GB)</th><th>Size(GB)</th><th>PercentFree(%)</th><th>LOW SPACE</th></tr>
<tr><td>K005</td><td>C:</td><td></td><td>76,5</td><td>111,0</td><td></td><td>False</td></tr> <tr><td>K005</td><td>U:</td><td>Nowy</td><td>87,5</td><td>465,8</td><td></td><td>False</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the content of the html. You should have edited your question instead of post an answer. It will probably gets deleted. Anways. Are you sure you changed `if ($_.'FreeSpace(GB)' -le 5)` to `if ($_.'FreeSpace(GB)' -le 100)`? It should work.

Comment: I could add a comment, too many characters. So I just typed: if ($_.'FreeSpace(GB)' -le 100) { And not work.

Comment: Please add the following line BEFORE the if statement: `Write-Host ("Value: '{0}', Condition: '{1}'" -f $_.'FreeSpace(GB)', ($_.'FreeSpace(GB)' -le 100))` Now run the script again and post the output from the console.

Comment: Console output: Value: '', Condition: 'True'
Value: '', Condition: 'True'

Comment: No problem. Console outpu: Value: '76,5', Condition: 'False'
Value: '87,5', Condition: 'False'

Comment: ok, now add `Write-Host ("Type: '{0}'" -f ($_.'FreeSpace(GB)').GetType())` before the if statement and post the result. It looks like the value is a string.

Comment: Yes, it`s string: Type: 'System.String'
Type: 'System.String'

Comment: ok. So you have to change the if statement to: `if ([float]::Parse($a.'FreeSpace(GB)') -le 100) {` and it should work. Also change the background-color form `#FBB917` to red if you want a red background (this one is orange - from your script)

Comment: Nice, it`s work! You had an error instead ($_.'FreeSpace(GB)') was ($a.'FreeSpace(GB)'), but corrected and running. I know the color has changed recently Thanks a lot!
Yet somehow I have to add test-connection and send e-mail to the report.

Comment: your welcome. You should try solve the remaining tasks yourself and post another question (containing what you tried so far) if you get stuck.

Comment: Yes I do. Thank you!