# Powershell - free disk space alert - add Test-connection

Tags: powershell

Ok, i try add Test-Connection and now the code look likes this:

```
$html=
@'
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  .alert {{
    background-color: #FB1717 }}
    .statusCom {{
    background-color: #FB1717
    }}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>SystemName</th><th>DeviceID</th><th>VolumeName</th><th>Size(GB)</th><th>FreeSpace(GB)</th><th>Status</th></tr>
{0}
</table>
</body></html>
'@

$entryTemplate = '<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td><td>{4}</td><td>{5}</td><td>{6}</td></tr>'
$alertEntryTemplate = '<tr class="alert"><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td><td>{4}</td><td>{5}</td><td>{6}</td></tr>'
$statusTemplate = '<tr class="statusCom"><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td><td>{4}</td><td>{5}</td><td>{6}</td><td>{7}</td></tr>'


Function Get-ComInfo {   
param(
$computers
)

#Here LOW Space thresold is lessthan 10% of the total size of the Volume
$PercentFree = @{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.freespace /1GB)}} 
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter "DriveType=3" -computer $computers |
Select SystemName,DeviceID,VolumeName,$PercentFree,@{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.size/1gb)}},@{name="PercentFree(%)";Expression={int}}

}
$servers = Get-Content U:\Users\xxx\Desktop\servers.txt 

$client = $servers
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName (Get-Content U:\Users\xxx\Desktop\servers.txt ) -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -Quiet) {
$entries = $servers | % { Get-ComInfo -computers $_ } | % {

    if ([float]::Parse($_.'FreeSpace(GB)') -le 5) {
        $alertEntryTemplate -f $_.SystemName, $_.DeviceID, $_.VolumeName, $_.'FreeSpace(GB)', $_.'Size(GB)', $_.'PercentFree(%)', $_.'LOW SPACE'
    }

    else {
        $entryTemplate -f $_.SystemName, $_.DeviceID, $_.VolumeName, $_.'FreeSpace(GB)', $_.'Size(GB)', $_.'PercentFree(%)', $_.'LOW SPACE'
    }
}
    }
    else{
        $statusTemplate -f $_.SystemName, $_.DeviceID, $_.VolumeName, $_.'FreeSpace(GB)', $_.'Size(GB)', $_.'PercentFree(%)', $_.'LOW SPACE', $_.'Status'
    }


$html -f ($entries -join ' ') | out-file U:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Drivess.html
$OutputFile = "U:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Drivess.html"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.xxx.com" 
$EmailFrom = "xxxx@xxx.com"
$EmailTo = "xxxx@xxx.com"
$Subject = "$computers PROGRES ;))"  
$body = (Get-Content $OutputFile) 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $false
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx");
$MailTextT =  Get-Content  -Path U:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Drivess.html -Raw
$msg = New-object Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $body)
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true  
$SMTPClient.Send($msg)
```

In html i add this:

```
.statusCom {{
    background-color: #FB1717
    }}
```

And:

```
$statusTemplate = '<tr class="statusCom"><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td><td>{4}</td><td>{5}</td><td>{6}</td><td>{7}</td></tr>'
```

And i have more than one computer and one is offline in my servers.txt it i get this error:

```
Get-WmiObject : Serwer RPC it is offline. (Expectiob HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At U:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test.ps1:36 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -filter "DriveType=3" -computer $comp ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

If i have one computer and it is offline a get this:

```
<tr class="statusCom"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

What i do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to add it yourself already? I don't know what you want your output to look like. All I see is code and put this in my code.

Comment: I see that you just got this answer recently from here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595516/powershell-free-disk-space-bgcolor-result-how-change/35596104#35596104

Comment: At each host I have to check if it is available, if there is no unsubscribe at nzawie that is offline and go to koljengo computer from the list.

Comment: @CodeObiect that's fine. But on Stack Overflow, it's expected that you have already attempted to perform the task yourself, and need help getting past a particular point you're stuck on. SO is not a code-writing service, please do not ask us to do it all for you.

Comment: I've tried to add this code, but did not give it effect. He's not in this code, because I did not know exactly where he was supposed to be

Comment: @CodeObiect that's not a good way to get help. You can't say "I added code but it's not working and I'm not showing it to you" and expect to get help. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if (Test-Connection -ComputerName COMPUTERNAME_HERE -Count 1 -EA SilentlyContinue) { "online" } else { "offline" }

You Need to take this *somewhere* into your script, this should be easily done.
You can use the Systemname as Computername, provided by the Get-ComInfo function and you need to extent your two templates by a {7} for online/offline information.

Comment: Thank you! I tried different codes and finally succeeded.